# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to fetch SVG images dynamically in my react component, but so far I'm getting this error **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module**. This is my code sample

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CustomSvgIcon } from '../../util/CustomSvgIcon';


const Icon = ({ iconName }: IconProps) => {
  const [menuIcon, setIcon] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (iconName) {
      import(`../../../assets/svg/${iconName}.svg`)
        .then((bla) => setIcon(bla.default))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <CustomSvgIcon>
      {menuIcon ? menuIcon : null}
    </CustomSvgIcon>
  );
};
```

This code works perfectly in the storybook, but when I use it in the react component it won't load images and that error pops. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved with setting some rules in webpack.config. It was issue with `.svg`. This is the rule that solved the issue:

```
{
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
          options: {
            icon: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```