# "TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module" on Vue/Vite vanilla setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vite

We have a vanilla Vue/Vite setup and I'm receiving `TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module` on sentry logs.

It seems like the errors are correlated in time with new deployment to prod, although I don't have enough data to confirm. It doesn't happen on local and appears only on deployed code.
I've seen some similar questions for react's setups, but none with a satisfactory response.
I've also found a [similar question regarding dynamically imported svgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488617/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-dynamically-imported-module), but our errors happen for full components.

The only place where we use dynamic imported components is on routing:

```js
export const router = createRouter({
  history: routerHistory,
  strict: true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: routes.homepage.name,
      component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '/overview',
          name: routes.overview.name,
          component: () => import('@/views/Overview.vue'),
        },
        // other similar routes
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

Our deps versions:

```js
    "vue": "^3.0.9",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.5",
    "vite": "^2.0.5",
```

Any additional information on this issue and how to debug it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible project available ?

Comment: Did you try using vanillaJS path references? `@/smth/smth` is VueMagic and might cause problems

Comment: Putting this here, If by chance helps anyone. 

I've seen similar error in our app. We're on Vue 3 + Vite with dynamic imports. Problem only occurred when using browser with uOrigin AdBlocker. Issue was we named one file `tracking-type.ts` which was then blocked by AdBlocker (duh, because of the name). Fix was simple rename to something that has no `tracking` in it :)

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm getting the same error: `Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://mywebsite/assets/HomePage.694cb716.js` . The file in question doesn't exist so can it be related to some sort of caching by the browser requesting an old chunk that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: im getting this error just importing JavaScript: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:4173/i18n/en.js

Comment: @zigomir Thanks, mate. That was the issue in my Vue 3 + Vite project! You saved my day!

Comment: @zigomir thanks for that, ublock was blocking my file called analytics.vue so apparently it's not just tracking.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When you dynamically import a route/component, during build it creates a separate chunk. By default, chunk filenames are *hashed* according to their content – `Overview.abc123.js`. If you don't change the component code, the hash remains the same. If the component code changes, the hash changes too - `Overview.32ab1c.js`. This is great for caching.

Now this is what happens when you get this error:

1. You deploy the application
2. Your Home chunk has a link to `/overview` route, which would load `Overview.abc123.js`
3. Client visits your site
4. You make changes in your code, not necessarily to the Overview component itself, but maybe to some children components that Overview imports.
5. You deploy changes, and Overview is built with a different hash now - `Overview.32ab1c.js`
6. Client clicks on `/overview` link - gets the `Failed to fetch dynamically imported module` error, because `Overview.abc123.js` no longer exists

That is why the errors correlate with deployments. One way to fix it is to not use lazy loaded routes, but that's not a great solution when you have many heavy routes - it will make your main bundle large

Comment: Yes! I reached this conclusion a while ago. I should have updated it in here, my bad.
Although, I haven't found a good solution too.
We're just ignoring the error for now. :(

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of the problem. For now, we, too, are ignoring the errors and asking users to "refresh and try again". But that's frustrating for both our team as well as the users. I wish the Vite team does something about this problem. With Vue 2 and webpack, this problem never occurred.

Comment: @Preetesh But I assume this error will not occur if the deployed application stays the same? Or in other words: Does this error only occur when the developer has recently redeployed the webapp and the browser clients have outdated caches?

Comment: @ShadowGames Mostly yes, it should not occur if the application stays the same. As other comments noted, it can happen if there's a typo, or the imported file does not exist, or the file extension is missing in the import path.

Comment: It's crazy. It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Like @Preetesh, we need to ask our users to refresh the page. Not a good solution right now, and it is frustrating because it is specific to Vite (with Webpack, no problem).
I will implement the Wouter Sioen's solution temporarily.

Comment: I couldn't find a bug for this, so have logged it https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11804

Comment: @Preetesh This is not magic. If you configured Webpack to bundle everything into a few big bundles, of course this would not happen. Are you sure you made the EXACT same setup using webpack? This will happen in ANY bundler that creates a bazillion different bundles to load, webpack not excluded. This is expected.

Comment: I've made a change inside a lazy-loaded component but I visited a different screen after deployment and still encountered the error.  The screen where the error was caught does not import the modified component

Comment: Thank's for this answer, this is an excellent explanation of the problem. For now, we, too, are ignoring the errors

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer correctly explains when this error is triggered but does not really provide a good solution.

The way I fixed this is by using an error handler on the router. This error handler makes sure that when this error occurs (so thus when a new version of the app is deployed), the next route change triggers a hard reload of the page instead of dynamically loading the modules. The code looks like this:

```
router.onError((error, to) => {
  if (error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module') || error.message.includes("Importing a module script failed")) {
    window.location = to.fullPath
  }
})
```

Where `router` is your vue-router instance.

Comment: A bit surprised as `router.onError` expects a callback function of type `ErrorHandler` which expects only an error. There is no `to` parameter. (using vue-router 3.x)

Comment: Your errors may be browser specific. For example Firefox and Safari:

`error loading a dynamically imported module`
`Importing a module script failed`

Comment: The spec dictates that module caching is to happen even if it fails. Chrome will still serve you the cached failure, even if you refresh, which means you need to employ cache busting. Have a look here for one such approach (framework agnostic): https://stackoverflow.com/a/76200536/200987

Comment: Should be `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @LéoCoco any idea on how to access 'to' route param?

Answer (score 26):

In my case the error was caused by not adding `.vue` extension to module name.

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent'
```

It worked in webpack setup, but with Vite file extension is required:

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent.vue'
```

Comment: Hey llyich, thanks for the reply.
I'm afraid it is not the case here as we're using the extension as shown in the `require` statements in the example. We use it everywhere.

Comment: I needed `.svelte` for my project, I feel dumb, was checking the file name and everything lol

Answer (score 22):

I had the exact same issue. In my case some routes worked and some didn't. The solution was relatively easy. I just restarted the dev server.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely would have spent a lot longer banging my head against a wall if I hadn't seen this.

Comment: Had the exact same problem when i added a new npm package. Restarting the dev server fixed it for me.. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is misleading. You can definitely get this error locally, and in that case restarting the dev server is a good fix, but the error is most likely not caused by lazy loaded routes. the original question asks about this error in the context of _production_ and _lazy loaded routes_.

Comment: This answer is for local environment and not production.

Answer (score 8):

Wouter Sioen's solution is good, but after this fix I encountered another problem when chunkLoad error occurs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullPath'). My solution to that was:

```
router.onError((error, to) => {
  if (
    error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module') ||
    error.message.includes('Importing a module script failed')
  ) {
    if (!to?.fullPath) {
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      window.location = to.fullPath;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

On my end, the solution was cleaning up cache and .vite in between a server restart.

```bash
# kill your dev server then
rm -rf node_modules/.cache node_modules/.vite;
# relaunch your server
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 2):

My situation was similar.
I found that my Quasar setup works fine on the initial page but not page that are loaded dynamically through an `import('../pages/page.vue');`.

Short response:
I replaced `import('../pages/TestPage.vue')` in the middle of the route file by `import TestPage from '../pages/TestPage.vue'` at the top.

More detailed response:

In my situation I don't expect to have much pages, a single bundle with no dynamic loading is fine with me.

The solution is to import statically every page I need.
In my `routes.ts` I import all the pages I need.

```
import IndexPage from '../pages/IndexPage.vue';
import TestPage from '../pages/TestPage.vue';
```

Then I serve them statically in my routes :

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: 'test', component: () => TestPage },
      { path: '', component: () => IndexPage }
  ],
  },
  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently expriencied this.  The error was caused by an empty href inside an a tag:  <a href="" @click="goToRoute">.  You can either remove the href or change the a tag to something else, ie. button.  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I caused this by accidentally mis-naming my component "VIewerPage.vue" with capital "I" that was difficult to notice.  I called it ViewerPage.vue in my router code and that caused this exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.onError((error, to) => {
  if (error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module')) {
    window.location = to.href
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I had an import in the current page component file which was outdated. Removing this import fixed the issue.

```
import NonexistingComp from '/components/NonExistingComp.vue';
```

I also had this error in my terminal:

> Failed to load url /components/NonExistingComp.vue (resolved id:
> /components/NonExistingComp.vue) in /components/PageComponent.vue.
> Does the file exist?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by not adding `.jsx` extension to a filename, where `.jsx` was the appropriate extension.

For example instead of `InboxScreen.stories.js`

use this `InboxScreen.stories.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

Using @domnantas' explanation and incorporating solutions from @Sioen and @Giedrius,

**I ensured there were no infinite redirects.**

```js
router.onError((error) => {
  console.error('router.onError', error)

  const isDeployError =
    error.message.includes('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module') ||
    error.message.includes('Importing a module script failed')

  if (isDeployError) errorReload(`Error during page load, ${error.message}`)
})
```

And the `errorReload` function:

```js
export const errorReload = (error: string, retries = 1) => {
  // Get the current URL
  const urlString = window.location.href

  // Create a URL object
  const url = new URL(urlString)
  const errRetries = parseInt(url.searchParams.get('errRetries') || '0')
  if (errRetries >= retries) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', url.pathname)
    // useSnackbarStore().add(error, { reload: true })
    return
  }

  // Update or add the query parameter
  url.searchParams.set('errRetries', String(errRetries + 1))

  // Reload the page with the updated URL
  window.location.href = url.toString()
}
```