# Using Swagger Parser with Svelte

Tags: json, import, swagger, svelte

I am trying to use Swagger Parser with my Svelte app. But I'm getting the following error message

> Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/src/routes/parser.svelte?

the Svelte file I'm in looks like

```svelte
<script>
    import SwaggerParser from '@apidevtools/swagger-parser';
    import schema from '../json-schemas.json';

    async function parse() {
        let parser = new SwaggerParser();


        try {
            let api = await parser.validate(schema);
            console.log('Yay! The API is valid.');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Onoes! The API is invalid. ' + err.message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I installed Swagger with `npm install @apidevtools/swagger-parser` 
and imported it with `import SwaggerParser from '@apidevtools/swagger-parser';`
So I don't know why its saying that it can't be loaded.

Also I forgot to originally mention my `package.json` has the type set to module `"type": "module"`

Comment: Isn't the error referring to the Svelte file itself rather than the parser?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. When I comment the line with the import the page loads. Unless there is some other place I need to import it, like a config file @H.B.

Comment: Have you tried [turning it off and on again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656201/546730)? 