# How to prevent chunks for ckeditor library in Vite + Vue 3 / Running into "failed to fetch dynamically imported module"

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, ckeditor5

We are using a CKEditor in a html editor (TheHtmlEditor.vue) that loads up 'contentItems' dynamically, depending on what content the user has stored at a given page previously.
However, revisiting that page at a later time, it fails loading randomly, due to loading errors of chunked imports:

GET https://gts.dev/node_modules/.vite/deps/@ckeditor_ckeditor5-typing_src_texttransformation__js.js?v=c9825b52 net::ERR_FAILED
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:223

TypeError: **Failed to fetch dynamically imported module**: https://gts.dev/src/components/cms/TheHtmlEditor.vue
...
createNewEditorInstanceEntry @ TheCmsPage.vue:88

(anonymous) @ TheCmsPage.vue:187
TheHtmlEditor.vue:62

GET https://gts.dev/node_modules/.vite/deps/@ckeditor_ckeditor5-list_src_todolist.js?v=33cc3966 net::ERR_FAILED
TheHtmlEditor.vue:63

GET https://gts.dev/node_modules/.vite/deps/@ckeditor_ckeditor5-basic-styles_src_underline__js.js?v=e4b76b9d net::ERR_FAILED
TheHtmlEditor.vue:64

GET https://gts.dev/node_modules/.vite/deps/@ckeditor_ckeditor5-undo_src_undo__js.js?v=c361c7f7 net::ERR_FAILED

---

In our content management system "TheCmsPage.vue" is a placeholder page for all the dynamically created content items that the user has previously added on each different page.

The template of "TheCmsPage.vue" looks as follows:

```
<template>
    <div class="container bg-vue">
        <TheNavbar />
        <main>
            <TheCmsSubBar />
            <div
                class="d-flex flex-column align-items-stretch flex-grow-1 bg-white p-3 pt-4 position-relative scrollarea"
            >
                <div class="ps-3">
                    <p class="fs-6 text-muted text-start">
                        {{ pageStore.getCurrentPage?.path }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <TheEditCmsPageBtnsForPageTop
                    v-if="pageStore.getCurrentPage != null"
                    :pageId="pageStore.getCurrentPage.id.toString()"
                />
                <div
                    v-for="componentInstance in propsForEditorInstances || [] as PropsForEditorInstance[]"
                    :key="componentInstance.contentItemId.toString()"
                >
                    <TheHtmlEditor :contentItemId="componentInstance.contentItemId" />
                </div>
                <TheButtonAddWysiwygEditor
                    v-if="pageStore.getCurrentPage != null"
                    :pageId="pageStore.getCurrentPage.id"
                    :buttonStyles="buttonStyles()"
                />
            </div>
        </main>
        <TheFooter />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import TheCmsSubBar from '@/components/cms/TheCmsSubBar.vue'
import TheButtonAddWysiwygEditor from '@/components/cms/TheButtonAddWysiwygEditor.vue'
import TheLoadingHtmlEditor from './TheLoadingHtmlEditor.vue'
import TheEditCmsPageBtnsForPageTop from './TheEditCmsPageBtnsForPageTop.vue'
import TheErrorCouldNotLoadHtmlEditor from './TheErrorCouldNotLoadHtmlEditor.vue'
import TheFooter from '@/components/TheFooter.vue'
import TheNavbar from '@/components/TheNavbar.vue'
import { defineAsyncComponent, onMounted, onUpdated, ref, watch } from 'vue'

import CmsManager from '@/managers/cms-manager'
import { useContentStore } from '@/stores/content-store'
import { usePageStore } from '@/stores/page-store'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user-store'
import { ContentItemDoc } from '@shadowgames/gts-shared-models'

const TheHtmlEditor = defineAsyncComponent({
    loader: () => import('@/components/cms/TheHtmlEditor.vue'),
    loadingComponent: TheLoadingHtmlEditor,
    delay: 200,
    errorComponent: TheErrorCouldNotLoadHtmlEditor,
    timeout: 30000
})


</script>
```

According to the answer of @domnantas here ["TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module" on Vue/Vite vanilla setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300341/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-dynamically-imported-module-on-vue-vite-vanilla-set),
asynchronous loading is problematic due to vite creating individual chunks of every contentItem that is being loaded on a single page.

In like 80% of the cases it leads to a "failed to fetch" error and in 20% of the time it works right way - which I think has to do with the dynamic loading of the contentItems. However this is awkward because a) when creating a "TheHtmlEditor" instance only the contentItemId is passed in, see the following editor component:

Snippet from "TheHtmlEditor.vue":

```
<template>
...

        <div :style="editorStyles">
            <ckeditor
                :editor="editor"
                v-model="editorData"
                :config="editorConfig"
                @ready="onEditorReady"
                :readonly="editorDisabled"
                :disabled="editorDisabled"
            ></ckeditor>
        </div>

</template>

<script>

import '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/dist/ckeditor.js'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js'
... // importing tons of other ckeditor plugins for every different feature of ckeditor...
import CmsManager from '@/managers/cms-manager'
import { useContentStore } from '@/stores/content-store'
import { usePageStore } from '@/stores/page-store'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user-store'

export default {
    name: 'TheHtmlEditor',
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    props: {
        contentItemId: String
    },
    setup() {
        const contentStore = useContentStore()
        const userStore = useUserStore()
        const pageId = usePageStore().getCurrentPage.id
        console.log('(TheHtmlEditor:setup()) pageId = ', pageId)
        return { pageId, contentStore, userStore }
    },

    // ...

    data() {
        //console.log('In data(): Configuring editor...')
        return {
            contentItem: null,
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorData: '',
            editorConfig: { ... }
        }
    },

    created() {
        console.log('(TheHtmlEditor:created()) Trying to loadAndAssignContentItem with id', this.contentItemId)
        this.loadAndAssignContentItem(this.contentItemId)
        this.createInterval()
    },
    methods: {
        assignContentItemToLocalProp(contentItem) {
            this.contentItem = contentItem
        },
        loadAndAssignContentItem(contentItemId) {
            useContentStore()
                .getContentItem(contentItemId)
                .then((contentItem) => {
                    console.log('(TheHtmlEditor:loadAndAssignContentItem()) Loaded contentItem', contentItem)
                    this.assignContentItemToLocalProp(contentItem)
                    this.assignContentToEditor()
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Could not load contentItem. Error: ', error)
                })
        },
        // ...
     }
}
</script>
```

... and b) as you can see, the loading happens in the created() lifecycle and should actually make the editor load the contentItem pull the data AFTER creation. However, when browsing to a page it seems both the async loading of the html editor AND the dynamic loading of a contentItem still occurs. Because: When commenting out the created() method the "failed fetch" error does not occur anymore.

So what would be the best approach to resolve this issue? Is there a way to prevent Vite from creating chunks for each and every single html editor? And what would need to be added to the vite.config.ts?

I haven't been able to get much of helpful information in the [rollup documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#code-splitting) nor from threads like this: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2756

Any ideas are much appreciated.