# Error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module" when using dynamic imports in Remix application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I am encountering an issue with dynamic imports in my Remix application. When attempting to dynamically import a module using the following code:

`const module = await import(`../lib/lang/lang-${language.toLowerCase()}.js`);`

I receive the error:

`TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:3000/build/lib/lang/lang-jp.js`

This issue only occurs when using dynamic imports; normal imports work as expected. Here are the relevant details:

Project Structure:

I have confirmed that the file paths in my dynamic import statements are correct.
The server is configured to handle dynamic imports, and there are no CORS issues.
The publicPath in remix.config.js is set appropriately.
The generated build output in the dist directory appears to be correct.

Code Samples:
Here is the working code using a normal import:

```
// Working Code
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const LangTranslation = ({language, string}) => {
  const [translation, setTranslation] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTranslation = async () => {
      try {
        let module;
        let languages;
        if (language === 'EN') {
          module = await import(`../lib/lang/lang-en.js`);
          languages = module.languagesEn;
        } 
         // rest of logic
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading language file:', error);
        // ... (fallback logic)
      }
    };

    loadTranslation();
  }, [language, string]);

  return <>{translation}</>;
};

LangTranslation.propTypes = {
  language: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  string: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default LangTranslation;
```

And here is the code using dynamic imports that causes the issue:

```
// Not working code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const LangTranslation = ({ language, string }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTranslation = async () => {
      try {
        const module = await import(`../lib/lang/lang-${language.toLowerCase()}.js`);
        // ... (rest of the logic)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading language file:', error);
        // ... (fallback logic)
      }
    };

    loadTranslation();
  }, [language, string]);

  return <>{/* ... */}</>;
};

LangTranslation.propTypes = {
  language: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  string: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default LangTranslation;
```

Additional Information:

I have checked the network requests in the browser's developer tools, and the request for the dynamic module (lang-jp.js) seems to be failing.

Question:

Any insights or suggestions on why dynamic imports might be failing in my Remix application would be greatly appreciated. Is there anything specific in Remix's configuration or Webpack settings that I should check? Thank you!

Comment: You may try keeping language file separated from bundle like you can host them as json file on any cloud platform or fetch it from your backend server.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the issue is related to the bundler & bundler configuration. source files changes When the app gets bundled (chunking) which results with failure.

check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300341/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-dynamically-imported-module-on-vue-vite-vanilla-set) for more insight

your bundler has many intermediary steps other than chanking, you need to take a closer look at it. it may also be related to filename resolution and caching.

Comment: Sans the link to the other SO post your answer seems little more than speculation and guesswork and should have probably just been a comment. If you feel the linked post answers this post's question then the correct action is to vote as duplicate.